# Dart await while(true) but users cannot input with stdin

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:io';
main() async {
  await loop();
  while(true){
    print('Your input:${stdin.readLineSync()}');
  }
}

loop(){
  print('stuck');
  //Future.delayed(Duration(days:5),(){});//works fine
  //while(true);//does not work
}
```

Why cannot users input anything when while(true) is being executed inside loop(), instead, Future. delayed works fine with stdin?

Comment: `loop()` should be marked as `async` and return (or not) `Future`, and do its work in Future or Isolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is *single-threaded*. That means that at most one piece of Dart code is running at a time (per isolate if you have isolates).

Code like `while(true);` is a tight loop that never stops. No other code will run in the same isolate until the loop ends, and the loop never ends. This is *busy waiting*, and it does not give other code time to run.

You never even get to the part of your code which calls `stdin.readLineSync()`.

The `await` in front of `loop()` does nothing, because the code never gets to it. It calls `loop` and stays there forever.

If you create a `Future.delayed(...)`, then ... it doesn't actually do anything. You are not returning it, so the `await` won't be waiting for it to complete. All you do is to create a timer, create a `Future` object, and when the timer runs out, something will happen which will complete the future. If you return the future, then the `await` will wait for that.

What did you want or expect this code to do?

Comment: So I just want to simulate two threads, one takes user inputs, the other one runs forever.

Comment: In that case, the "thread" that runs forever needs to take a break occasionally. It's not a real thread, as in real concurrent execution, you'd need to use isolates for that.